# 100% text box width using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap theme and trying to build a header first. In the header how can i make text field to consume the unused space and width to 100% using bootstrap.?

**Code Sample**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Smart App</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ali Adnan <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Manage Apps</a></li></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline" style="width:60%" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Search</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

Comment: it's really complicated to imagine this code... make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'form-group' and try something like this...

```
.navbar-form {width:62%;white-space:nowrap;}
```

It won't completely fill the right space (due to the floating right nav), but it will take up most of the navbar.

Demo: http://bootply.com/91377#

Comment: Thanks Skelly for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:100% !important;">
```

to force your css to use 100% of the space.